# Wrap text inside of an element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, mysql

I have some elements like this:

```
<div class="box">
    Team 1 - #5
</div>

<div class="box">
    Team 2 - #3
</div>
```

And now I need to colorize these boxes like team 1 is getting blue and team 2 is getting red. But how can I do this?

Every Team is a member of a big clan which provides the color of the team. So I have a table with the clan color.

I'm using a MySQL table (two tables teams and clans). In the team table I have a foreign key field for the clan ID in the clan table

Comment: what the table is concerned of database , html ?? Please explain your question more as you can ..

Comment: @ismaelw was right. I'm using a MySQL table for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that’s easy. If you have a table with your clan and its colors you have likely a field in your team table where the clan is written in with a foreign key right?

So your query should also get the color of the clan with an inner join.

so you can export the field of the clan color as class into your code like this:

```
<div class="box team-color-<?php echo $clan_color; ?>">
    Team 1 - #3
</div>
```

And then you can set the color thing in CSS with "`.team-color-[CLANCOLORVARIABLE] {}`"

But if you want to wrap your text with jQuery as asked you could do this:

So it would be perfect if you have your color as a classname in your elements. Then in jQuery you can do something like this:

```
$('.team-color-black').each(function() {
   var content = $(this).text;
   content.html('<span class="colorsetting">' + content + '</span>');
});
```

Then your text gets wrapped and can be formatted with css settings

Comment: @MilindAnantwar thanks for your tip. I was deep in thoughts while reading and writing.

Comment: You are definitely right! I think I don't need the wrapping of the text for I can just output my clan color as class name off the element.

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN TRY THIS ONE:

```
 <div class="box">
    <span>Team 1 - #5</span>
    <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
<br />
<div class="box1">
   <span> Team 2 - #3</span>
     <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('.box p').wrapAll('<div class="moreInfo"></div>');
$('.box1 p').wrapAll('<div class="moreInfo"></div>');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/vwmHF/72/)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it using jQuery `each` function like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var color = ['red','green'];
 $('.box').each(function(index){
    $(this).css('background',color[index]);
});
```

Comment: But with this code every box gets the same color. That's not what he wants to have as you can read in his question.

Comment: You can use a color array. and use it within the each loop

Comment: Yeah but for this you need to know in which clan the team is to select the right color.

Comment: Yeah this would work somehow. But he wants to set the right color based on the clan a team is in. And that for you need to output the clan color from the database.